# How to display the image name of uploaded image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am uploading an image and in one td I also put the image name. But my problem is when I upload a image, the image name repeats in all the rows which should not. What is wrong with this? Thanks.

This is my fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/g31ykfy8/

sample code:

```
$scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
$scope.photoChanged = function (files, index) {
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
        var index = this.$index;
       $scope.imgName = files[0].name;
        if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.thumbnail[index] = {dataUrl: e.target.result};
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a same size of array for file names and based on index you need to push file names in photoChanged event.

Below is the working code for same.

```
angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test').controller('UploadCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout,$parse) {
     $scope.imgName ='';
    $scope.thumbnail = {
        dataUrl: []
    };
        $scope.fileNames = [,,,,];
    $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
    $scope.photoChanged = function (files, index) {
        if (files != null) {
            var index = this.$index;
          var file = files[0];           
          $scope.fileNames[index] = files[0].name;
          $scope.$apply();
            if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.thumbnail[index] = {dataUrl: e.target.result};
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The markup looks something like below.

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
                <td>{{i}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" />
                    <img ng-src="{{ thumbnail[$index].dataUrl }}" height="50px" />
                </td>
              <td>
                {{fileNames[$index]}}                
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The working fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5o6haym/).

Comment: I changed the `$scope.fileNames =[,,,,]` to `$scope.fileNames = []`. Still working. Thanks